# SQL update statement is updating

Tags: sql, sql-update, multiple-tables

I'm confounded by an Update statement that seems easy on the surface.  I need to update the values in 4 columns in Table1 with values from Table2 based on matching two separate columns from each table.  Here is the general syntax:

```
Update Table1 
set field1 = [table2 field1]
, field2 = [table2 field2]
, field3 = [table2 field3]
, field4 = [table2 field4]
--select *
from Table2 p inner join Table1 c
on p.matchfield1 = c.matchfield1 and p.matchfield2 = c.matchfield2
where c.database_id = 1 --qualifier since join clause may not provide unique result set 
and p.matchfield1 = 123456 --to test the statement on a single record first
```

When I run the clause as a select statement I get a single record as expected.  However, when I run the update clause using the same 'from' language I find that the query updates EVERY row in Table1 with the values from Table2 where matchfield1 = 123456.

I'm wondering if I need to further clarify my where clause to qualify based on the matchfield2 value (eamil address in my example) so I'd add to the end of the statement 'and p.matchfield2 = 'email@address.com''.

I suspect I'm a very small tweak away from making this work but in the meantime it's making me half crazy.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008.  Sorry I didn't add that to the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a JOIN on the same table, try this (assuming you are using SQL Server)...

```
UPDATE Table1 
    set field1 = [table2 field1]
    , field2 = [table2 field2]
    , field3 = [table2 field3]
    , field4 = [table2 field4] 
FROM Table2 p        
WHERE database_id = 1 
    AND p.matchfield1 = 123456
    AND p.matchfield1 = matchfield1 AND p.matchfield2 = matchfield2
```

You could also modify your query to tighten the filtering by adding `AND c.matchfield1 = matchfield1 AND c.matchfield2 = matchfield2` to the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It was very helpful.  I was assuming that I had to establish the join between table1 and table2 before I could add the database_id = 1 to the where clause.  I was able to get this to work!  Thanks again!

Comment: @user3167010 The Table you are trying to update works as Table1 so the `FROM` can just have the other tables.